# Apply all props to grandchild component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say I have a component Parent, a Child and a Grandchild.
In Parent, I'm passing the props `grandchildParams`

In Child, I have something like

```
<template>
 <p> some extra stuff</p>
 <Grandchild>
</template>
```

and I'd like to have every prop from `grandchildParams` being applied in the template to it. For example:

Let's say I have it like { label: 'foo', value: 'bar' }
I'd like to have in the Child component the following

```
<template>
 <p> some extra stuff</p>
 <Grandchild :label='props.label' :value='props.value'>
</template>
```

But in a way that it works dynamically, without needing to mention `label` and `value` or any new value I might add

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

Comment: @EstusFlask this is actually what I was looking for. Do you mind posting an answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are inherited by default by root element in component template, this behaviour is [documented](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html).

Default behaviour [can be disabled](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) with `inheritAttrs: false` component option.

In order to pass attributes to another element, this needs to be done explicitly by using `$attrs` object:

```
<template>
 <p> some extra stuff</p>
 <Grandchild v-bind="$attrs">
</template>
```

Comment: Best answer for this kind of requirement!

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are using props, you need to pass data in every component:

**Parent**

```
<template>
 <Child :value="myData.value" :label="myData.label"></Child>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
     myData:{label:'foo', value:'bar'}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
 <Child :value="value" :label="label"></Child>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:['value','label']
}
</script>
```

**Grand Child**

```
<template>
  <p>{{ label }} : {{ value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:['value','label']
}
</script>
```

2- Another approach is using `provide` and `inject`

**Parent**

```
<script>
export default {
 data(){
    return{
     myData:{label:'foo', value:'bar'}
    }
 },
 provide(){
  return{
    myData:this.myData
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

**Grand Child**

```
<template>
  <p>{{ myData.label }} - {{ myData.value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject:['myData']
}
</script>
```

Comment: So there is no way to this dynamically? Granchild is a third-party library that I use and I'd like to wrap it with a few more things. But the issue is that it can have a lot of properties

Comment: @EduardoSousa I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Check This one:

**Parent**

```
<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue"
export default {
  components:{
    Child
  },
  data(){
    return{
      myData:{label:'Name', value:'John'}
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <child :pass="myData"></child>
</template>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
  <grand-child v-bind="$props"></grand-child>
</template>

<script>
import GrandChild from "./GrandChild.vue"

export default{
  components:{GrandChild},
  props:['pass']
}
</script>
```

**Grand Child**

```
<template>
  <p>{{ pass.label }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:["pass"]
}
</script>
```